# Fluent NHibernate - Mapeamento Chave Composta

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

Saudações,

Estou com uma dificuldade e não consigo resolver.

Tenho uma aplicação onde criei o mapeamento e estava tudo funcionando perfeitamente, porém agora preciso alterá-lo e é aí que surge o problema:

Utilizei o Fluente NHibernate para o ORM.

Preciso criar o mapeamento utilizando uma chave composta, ou seja, em linguagem SQL ficaria algo assim:

```
select
    *
from
    t1
inner join
    t2
        on  t1.codigo = t2.codigo
        and t1.versao = t2.versao;
```

E não consigo mapear o "and" do join.

Meu mapeamento está assim:

```
public class T1Map : ClassMap<T1>{
    public T2Map() {
        Table("TB_WF_T1");
        Id(x => x.Codigo, "CD_T1").GeneratedBy.Sequence("SEQ_TB_WF_T1");
        Map(x => x.Versao, "CD_VERSAO");
        HasMany(x => x.T2).KeyColumn("FK_CODIGO_T1").LazyLoad().Inverse().Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }        
}

public class T2Map : ClassMap<T2>{
    public T2Map() {
        Table("TB_WF_T2");
        Id(x => x.Codigo, "CD_T2").GeneratedBy.Sequence("SEQ_TB_WF_T2");
        Map(x => x.Versao, "CD_VERSAO");
        References(x => x.T1).Column("FK_CODIGO_T1").LazyLoad().Cascade.None();
    }
}
```

Minha dúvida é como faço o mapeamento tanto do campo "CODIGO" quanto do campo "VERSAO".

Existe alguma maneira de realizar esse mapeamento?

Qualquer dica que alguem puder me ajudar, ficarei muito agradecido.

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver o problema com a minha resposta abaixo? caso sim selecione a minha resposta como resolvido. Senão eu ainda posso te ajudar em algo.

Comment: Vou tentar agora... Já já eu posto o resultado.

Comment: Danilo, eu vou precisar fazer algumas modificações na estrutura da minha aplicação para realizar os testes. Assim que eu terminar, eu aviso se deu certo.

Answer (score 3):

Eu utilizo o CompositeId() do FluentNHibernate, e utilizo o reference. o HasMany é se é alguma coleção que quero carregar junto. Pelo seu código você já deve saber a diferença.

```
CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.Id, "idB")//se for uma referencia(entidade)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Id2, "idB2");//se for uma propriedade(int/long)
```

---

Segue um exemplo se for uma classe com **KeyProperty** e **KeyReference**:
([Esse Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378741/fluent-nhibernate-compositeid-to-mapped-class))

```
    public class TestChildMap : ClassMap<TestChild>
    {
        public TestChildMap()
        {
            Table("TestChild");
            CompositeId()
                .KeyProperty(x => x.ChildName, "ChildName")
                .KeyReference(x => x.Parent, "TestParentId");
    Map(x => x.Age);
            References(x => x.Parent, "TestParentId")
     .Not.Insert();  //  will avoid "Index was out of range" error on insert
    }
```

---

Segue um exemplo se for uma classe apenas com **KeyReference**:

```
public class MapEmpresaProduto : MapBase<EmpresaProduto>
    {
        public MapEmpresaProduto()
        {
            Table("EmpresaProduto");
            CompositeId()
                .KeyReference(x => x.Empresa, "IdEmpresa")
                .KeyReference(x => x.Produto, "IdProduto");

            References(x => x.Empresa)
                .Not.Nullable()
                .Fetch.Join()
                .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
                .Column("IdEmpresa")//linko o KeyReference(x => x.Empresa, "IdEmpresa") atraves do column name.
                .ReadOnly();

            References(x => x.Produto)
                .Not.Nullable(

)
                .Fetch.Join()
                .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
                .Column("IdProduto")
                .ReadOnly();
        }
    }
```

Minha entidade **EmpresaProduto**:

```
public class EmpresaProduto : EntidadeAuditavelSemId
    {
        public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }

        public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }

        protected EmpresaProduto()
        {
        }
        public EmpresaProduto(Empresa empresa, Produto produto) : this()
        {
            Produto = produto;
            Empresa = empresa;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object entity)
        {
            if (entity == null || !(entity is EmpresaProduto))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Mesmas instâncias devem ser consideradas iguais
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, entity))
            {
                return true;
            }

            // Objetos transientes não são considerados iguais
            var other = (EmpresaProduto)entity;
            var typeOfThis = GetType();
            var typeOfOther = other.GetType();
            if (!typeOfThis.IsAssignableFrom(typeOfOther) && !typeOfOther.IsAssignableFrom(typeOfThis))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return Produto.Id.Equals(other.Produto.Id) && Empresa.Id.Equals(other.Empresa.Id);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                var hash = GetType().GetHashCode();
                hash = (hash * 31) ^ Produto.GetHashCode();
                hash = (hash * 31) ^ Empresa.GetHashCode();

                return hash;
            }
        }
    }
```

**OBS:** Já fiz inumeros testes e o SQLServer até agora se destacou, sendo index criados com nomes estranhos e errados no MYSQL e postgress. Então caso o seu banco não for sqlserver tenha cuidado. (O problema esta realmente no conector e não no fluent em si).

Comment: Danilo, não deu certo. Nesse trecho que você me deu como exemplo, onde que eu especifico qual é a segunda cláusula (chave composta) para o join?

Comment: é eu realmente não entendi oque voce quer... no codigo postado vc esta utilizando em 'public class ExclusaoMap' tanto CompositeId() como Id(), isso esta me deixando confuso, qual é a chave da tabela Exclusao? Se for uma chave composta deve se utilizar CompositeId(), senão Id(). Esse mapeamento tambem estou percebendo que não é necessario, voce pode fazer 2 queries no LINQ com um where(x => x.Codigo == codigo && x.versao == versao)... Entao esta bem confuso mesmo. De uma pesquisada em alguns exemplos em ingles, que talvez melhore sua ideia de como fazer isso.

Comment: Eu acho que compliquei quando postei as classes. Amanhã eu posto como estava e o que preciso, ficará mais fácil para você conseguir me ajudar.

Comment: Danilo, eu descrevi em baixo o que eu preciso e como está. Veja se entende e se consegue me ajudar.

Comment: Para resolver seu problema, o campo Versao Deve ser Um ForegnKey/PrimaryKey Pois não é usual voce fazer um join por propriedades basicas... Nao conseguirei resolver seu problema, talvez alguem possa me ajudar para solucionar esse misterio kkk

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855135/fluent-nhibernate-mapping-one-to-many-using-2-columns esse link talvez te ajude.